# Formal way to test what kind of differencing is necessary?

Tags: data-transformation, lasso, logarithm, high-dimensional, differencing

I'm working on a project that concerns time series data for South-Africa. My series has 34 explanatory variables and only (!) 30 yearly observations. The analysis is meant to be high-dimensional, hence I chose to have p>n. My y-dependent variable is the under-5-mortality-rate and I have collected 34 explanatory variables ranging from HIV infection/immunization data to school enrolment. For my analysis, I was wondering whether there exists a formal way to test whether your time series data needs a

```
dif(log) transformation, or

dif() transformation?
```

As I only have 30 observations, I don't really have much changing variance over time. Besides, most of my series seem to show a clear trend (either up- or downwards) as Kenya has developed (?) quite well over the past 30 years.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to difference your data? What will you do with it?

Comment: Unit root test?